# I can't create a file at android pie

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to create file to upload into server in android pie,
when I'm using android lower than API 28 I'm using like this

```java
    File file = new File(uri);
```

in android pie, uri is going like this
`content://downloads/public_downloads/114/`

in android lower than pie, I get uri like this
`external_storage/com.blah/blah/blah.pdf`

here I try

```
class PickImage : FlutterActivity() {
 val intent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
                addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                type = "application/pdf"
            }
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < KITKAT")
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == this.requestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                val uri = data?.data
                val file = File(uri)
         //this error when im using android pie
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

}
```

please someone help. thanks

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` opens a document, not a file. Use `ContentResolver` to work with the document, such as using `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` to write to the document.

Comment: @CommonsWare any document for learn about it ? or some sample code ?

Comment: The Storage Access Framework is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider). [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/tree/v0.4/Diceware) and [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/tree/v0.4/ContentEditor) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) demonstrate its use.